# Custom JSON response with Java / Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Working in a Java 7 Spring 3 (Java based configuration) tomcat application.
I have two objects that require merging to create one single JSON response.

The objects can be described in their individual JSON as

Object 1

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "age": 20,
    "siblings": [{"sisters":1,"brothers":1}]
}
```

Object 2

**NOTE:** A HashMap - so keys aren't finite.

```
{
    "school": { "teachers": [{"name": "Mr Danes"}] },
    "work": { "workplaces": [{"name": "sainsburys"}] },
    ...: { ... }
}
```

The requirement is to have a merged view as

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "age": 20,
    "siblings": [{"sisters":1,"brothers":1}],
    "school": { "teachers": [{"name": "Mr Danes"}] },
    "work": { "workplaces": [{"name": "sainsburys"}] }
}
```

Ideally I'd be able to deal with this in the controller with JSONObjects rather than delving into the objects themselves (as they are shared objects across a number projects)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not try what you are attempting.  Just create a new web tier POJO which is a composite of the two.  The combined POJO will be easier to debug, easier to unit test, and generally more maintainable.

In other words: Don't be cute. Keep it simple.

Comment: So I took the route of creating a POJO- and along with `@JSONUnwrapped` and `@JSONAnyGetter` (for the HashMap) to force the responseBody JSON into a format I required, I was able to achieve what I set out to do.